# ClassNotFoundException with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, servlets, apache-poi

I am using apache poi v3.9 and following statement is always giving classdefinitionnotfound exception

```
       HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(file);


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at com.anz.actions.ConverterAction.execute(ConverterAction.java:39)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Even though I have included all jars in my build path:

```
poi
poi-scratchpad
poi-ooxml
poi-ooxml-schemas 
poi-examples 
ooxml-schemas
```

Comment: Could you please confirm that you also include jars in the final WAR (I assume you run it on Tomcat), in the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Build path isn't enough, you need to get them into the WAR too!

Comment: Thanks lppiepiora right now I am doing all in eclipse.I believe v3.9 of POI is currupted but I am getting same error even after new library updates.

Comment: I would still guess that they are not included in WAR, when you go to Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export, are the files marked as exported? They should be.

Comment: Acc to findjar.com (http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html) you don't have the correct set of jars in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the libraries may get corrupted... please remove all jars and add again, clean and run the app..

Comment: Thank You Sankumarsingh, I strongly believe the jar is corrupted but I am not able to find poi v3.8 or below. I downloaded poi3.9 libraries multiple times and updated to build path everytime it is giving same exception.

Comment: download 3.8 and below from here http://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/  for 3.8 its http://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip